# example assignment operator for non-invokables?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I have this assignment operator for invokable `f`s.

```
template <typename F>
auto operator=(F&& f) -> decltype(f(), *this);
```

I would also need one for non-invokable `f`s, so there would be no ambiguity when assigning those.

Comment: Just dispatch internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class F>
auto assign_impl(F&& f, int) -> decltype((void) f(), *this) {
    // f() is valid ...
}

template<class F>
auto assign_impl(F&& f, long) -> decltype(*this) {
    // everything else
}

template<class F>
auto operator=(F&& f) -> decltype(*this) { 
    return assign_impl(std::forward<F>(f), 0);
}
```

Comment: Won't the int overload always be called?

Comment: @user1095108 Only if `f()` is a valid expression. Otherwise it SFINAE's out.

Comment: Yes, yes, I see now. Why the cast to void?

Comment: @user1095108 Defend against overloaded commas.

Answer (score 0):

I've transformed T.C.s answer into a type trait and am using that now.

```
namespace
{

template <typename F, typename ...A>
auto f(int) -> decltype(
  (void)::std::declval<F>()(::std::declval<A>()...),
  ::std::true_type{}
);

template <typename F, typename ...A>
auto f(long) -> ::std::false_type;

}

template <typename F, typename ...A>
struct is_invokable : decltype(f<F, A...>(0))
{
};
```

Comment: Heh, if you want a trait, the `void_t` trick is probably cleaner.

Comment: Such trait there's on the way http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0077r0.html

Comment: @T.C. Please expand your answer